# Two time dependent covariates in SPSS, Possible?

Tags: spss

My data has three covariates, one static from baseline and two covariates that are time dependent. They are binominal and occurs some time after start of follow-up. Both are significant in univariate analysis. The SPSS manual hints that it would be possible to include both in an analysis but I cannot fathom how. Is this possible and how to go about it?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible using SPSS syntax. I think you have to look at the command that defines the time-dependent variable, and create similar ones for your other variables, with the same format. After that you can enter these time-dependent variables, just computed, in the Cox model.

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked like a charm. The planning s back on track :).